# How to fix the error "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause" when updating a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I rewrite the query below to avoid the error "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"?

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = meta_value + 'A' WHERE (SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts A
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta B ON B.post_id = A.id WHERE A.post_type = 'player' AND
B.meta_key ='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc') = 'Eric Bledsoe'
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to do.  Your query is either updating all rows in `wp_postmeta` or none of them.  I doubt that is the intention.  In addition, you have `meta_value + 'A'` which will return an error in MySQL.

Comment: `meta_value + 'A'` will cast the values to a numeric type and add them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a MySQL limitation.  You can use a `join` instead.  This is one guess on what you intend with your query:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta pm JOIN
       wp_posts p
       ON pm.post_id = p.id AND
          p.post_type = 'player' AND
          pm.meta_key ='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'
    SET pm.meta_value = CONCAT(pm.meta_value, 'A')
WHERE p.post_title = 'Eric Bledsoe';
```

As mentioned in the comment, your query either updates all rows in `wp_postmeta` or none of them.  The subquery has no correlation clause to the outer query.